# Problem while installing tzdata-java package (unmet dependencies)

Tags: debian, package-management, debian-squeeze, apt-get

I got a Debian 6.0 at home, upgrade from Lenny. I need to install the `tzdata-java` package but when I do an `apt-get install` I receive this message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> tzdata-java: Depends: tzdata (= 2011c-0squeeze1) but 2011d-0lenny1 is to be installed
>
> E: Broken packages

I searched on the web but I don't understand this error means.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem on squeeze, but this answer should be applicable to older versions as well. Simply change `tzdata`'s version numbers as needed.

First, do an `apt-cache showpkg tzdata`:

```
raphael@hydra:~$ apt-cache showpkg tzdata-java
Package: tzdata-java
Versions: 
   (snip)

Dependencies: 
2011k-0squeeze1 - tzdata (5 2011k-0squeeze1) 
Provides: 
2011k-0squeeze1 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

As you can see, it depends on `tzdata (2011k-0squeeze1)` - at least on my system. Now let's take a look at `tzdata`:

```
raphael@hydra:~$ apt-cache showpkg tzdata
Package: tzdata
Versions: 
   (snip)

Provides: 
2011l-0squeeze1 - tzdata-squeeze 
2011k-0squeeze1 - tzdata-squeeze 
Reverse Provides:
```

Oh, look, I've already got the old `2011k` and the new `2011l` installed. I'm not sure why  it doesn't work, however, we can force apt-get to downgrade`tzdata` which, as we'll see, is going to create a tear in spacetime:

```
raphael@hydra:~$ sudo apt-get install tzdata=2011k-0squeeze1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  tzdata
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 630 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    (snip)
dpkg: warning: downgrading tzdata from 2011l-0squeeze1 to 2011k-0squeeze1.
(Reading database ... 167509 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace tzdata 2011l-0squeeze1 (using .../tzdata_2011k-0squeeze1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement tzdata ...
Setting up tzdata (2011k-0squeeze1) ...
    (snip)
```

Now you might think, hey, if I run the update manager it will install the newer tzdata! But no, it won't:

```
raphael@hydra:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

(Schrödinger's package strikes back.)

Lo and behold, now I can install `tzdata-java`:

```
raphael@hydra:~$ sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tzdata-java
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 143 kB of archives.
   (snip)
```